# Is something like "my friend's code" or "code from other developer" just noise?

Tags: discussion, edits

Sometimes, the OP says the code came from their friends like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531515).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990) is a more extreme one, where the OP has weird code and says it came from the "original developer", but I suspect the "original developer" is just the OP and they used the term "original developer" to avoid being embarrassed!

Just like "I'm a beginner", I think the origin of the code is irrelevant to the question. So my question is, is something like "code from my friend" just noise and should it be removed?

Comment: That is a joke question.  They were popular in the early days of SO, the tone was set by [this fake question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator) afaik.  Thank heavens that's all over and done with.

Comment: It can be useful to know if you have no control over the original source code (or parts of it), but having no control over it is not the same as shirking what responsibility one *does* in fact have over it.

Comment: Say, hypothetically, if a friend of mine...

Comment: `The original developer is no longer available. Presumably due to what happened just after (s)he ran that code for the first time.` That's the most amazing thing I've ever read

Comment: @HansPassant - Why is that question "fake"? In my opinion the only problem with it is that so many people felt a need to post duplicate answers to it.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I think Hans's comment was fake. ;)

Comment: One question is from 2012, and one from 2014...

Comment: No, it is not just noise. It tells us that the asker did not write the code himself, and does not know everything about it. Such information can be important for clarification comments.

Comment: Hi @gstestso.  Given that you are an extremely new user - **no**, for now give it a miss.  Don't go around making "stylistic edits" until you have a lot of experience and points. It's worth remembering stylistic edits are **incredibly annoying** even to newb users and even to non-native-English-writer users.  I would honestly suggest "just don't do it" and more or less "mind your own business" your first year or two on the site.  I'm sure you have a lot of expert technical expertise in your own field: get to work doing ***your own excellent writing*** in Answers.

Comment: In many cases "my friend" means "my professor" who asked to explain what the code does (to pass the test). IMHO the standard automatic response should be "ask your friend first".

Comment: @13aal was it one of the 'binary bomb' assembler questions?

Comment: What is confusing me is the fact that the OP of the second link has 47k rep

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's a useful VLQ flag.  You see "code from my friend" and it's 99.9% sure to be a code dump with no inputs, outputs, error messages, logs or debugging details,  Worse, it implies that there is no point in asking for them in comments.

Such phrases should be kept since it helps reduce the decision time required before down and close-voting.

Comment: A good point, and one I'm afraid I have ignored up until now. I wouldn't have edited a question only to remove this sort of text, but I would remove it if editing for some other reason.

Comment: Such a statement definitely has value early on. However, if somehow later, the question ends up producing good answers and being useful, it would add value to remove it.

Comment: This is an excellent point.  Leave it alone for moderators to look at.

Answer (score 17):

Both [Martin James](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322958/is-something-like-my-friends-code-or-code-from-other-developer-a-kind-of-no/322964#322964) and [AdrianHHH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322958/is-something-like-my-friends-code-or-code-from-other-developer-a-kind-of-no/322961#322961) are correct in an extent.

Firstly, in most cases the phrase is noise.  We don't need to know who wrote the code to be able to answer the question (although in very rare cases it may be useful to know if the code in question wasn't written by the OP).

However, the proper way to handle it is to just handle it the same way as you do any other edits to posts with noise in it.  **Do not remove it for the sake of removing it**.  That goes for "Thanks", signatures, and anything else extra added to posts.

If the post can be made acceptable with some edits, then by all means edit it out while cleaning up the rest of the post.  But if the post is not salvageable without significant effort by the original asker, then don't waste your time.  Just downvote and/or vote-to-close as appropriate.  No sense bumping a bad & noisy post just to remove that kind of fluff.

Comment: Vote to close you think is appropriate based on an edit?  That is the absolute issue of SE and SO in general - every other thing is closed.  I'm starting to hate it.

Comment: @JonH I think you are misreading the post.  The point is there is no reason to edit out the fluff if the post is of poor quality and cannot be salvaged without significant input from the OP.  If the post is in that state than it is usually close worthy (unclear, too broad, and/or off-topic), so it should be moderated appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Ask yourself whether the answers will change depending on knowing that the person writing the question is, or is not, not the author of the code? I think not. It might if we personally knew the two people involved but Stack Overflow is mostly anonymous. We have peoples user-names but almost nothing more about them. We might look at a person's profile but that only gives details the author of the question. Here on Stack Overflow the question is important, knowing who wrote the question and the answer is (or should be) of of no importance.

If you believe that the underlying question is good but has other aspects that need improving then my recommendation is to treat those statements as noise and delete them - at the same time as fixing and improving other issues. Just removing these statements would not be a sufficient reason to edit the question.

Comment: All of this assumes that the post is worth fixing. If it isn't worth fixing, then don't edit, just downvote and/or vtc as appropriate

Comment: @psubsee2003 You are confirming my point about *"when editing to improve a question"*.

Comment: The problem is (and why I mentioned it) is that it is sort of lost at the end of your post and looks like an afterthought.  It is an important point as too many people just hunt for specific things to remove and ignore the rest, then just say "but `<insert meta link here>` told me I must remove it", and deserves to be a key part of the answer

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you for explaining. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I remove stuff like that: it's not relevant to the question and provides no actionable information.

I disagree with the idea it shouldn't be removed "just for the sake of removing it"; while minor, it's still an improvement. I wouldn't *only* remove the noise if the rest of the question isn't *also* of value, or least on the right track–if it needs more work, do that work as well.

Comment: Gstestso still has to provide a better example, but won't removing this just leave "(please|plz)+ explain this code to me" in most cases?

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, removing just one thing will leave other different things there. Other non-actionable stuff that doesn't provide value should also be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example where I have asked a question with a similar phrase.

[What is the purpose of these superfluous curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317601/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-superfluous-curly-braces)

I think it is a good idea to leave the phrase in as it tells people that the person asking the question will have no more information about its purpose, especially in the case above for me where I was asking about the functionality of the code. If someone just turned around and said "why did you do that?" to me, it would be a bit silly I think.